# Constuct a function that plus equations

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to construct a function that plus equations.
For example:

```
SomaEqns[eq1,eq2,...] == eq1 + eq2 + ...
```

It's possible do that with recursive way? Using less then possible the functions of Mathematica.

I know Mathematica already can do that.
It's just for exercise.

Comment: perhaps you'll find [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) helpful for a functional approach that circumvents possible problems with recursion limits

Comment: By "It's possible do that with recursive way? Using less then possible the functions of Mathematica.", I assume you are looking for a solution that uses recursion and does not use `Thread`, `Fold`, etc. One way to do this
`f[{eqn_}] := eqn`
`f[eqn_List] := First[eqn] + f[Rest[eqn]]`
f[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}] gives eq1 + eq2 + eq3 + eq4

Comment: `SomaEqns = Plus`?

Comment: Something like that @RohitNamjoshi. But in this case I don't want to write my equations as a `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive way (like Rohit's comment but without the list):

```
f[first_, rest__] := first + f[rest]
f[last_] := last

f[1, x, x^2, x^3]
```

> `1 + x + x^2 + x^3`

But note that `Plus` is exactly what you describe (as pointed out what AccidentalFourierTransform):

```
f[eqns__] := Plus[eqns]
f[1, x, x^2, x^3]
```

> `1 + x + x^2 + x^3`